# How to get 'test' branch into 'master' when 'test' is a branch of 'dev'?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Looking at the network graph for a github project, I see 3 branches of interest; master, test, dev.

Looking at the github network graph further, I am led to believe that test is a branch of dev instead of a branch from master.

At some point, I will want to put the contents of test into master.

Will I need to delete master and create a new branch called master from test in order to "get" test into master? By the way, I would like to keep the master history so I can roll back to an earlier commit if needed. So, deleting sounds bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just merge `test` into `master` then.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge test
```

A statement like "test is a branch of dev instead of a branch of master" isn't really true wit Git. `test` might have branched off of commits from `dev`, but assuming that `dev` branched off of `master` at some point, then by the transitive property `test` branched off of `master` too.

Comment: I was hoping that was the case. Yes, dev branched off of master. Thanks!